# Android: Special charaters in button names

Tags: android, button

How do I have special characters such as greek/latin letters, longer dashes etc in my button text name? In the sample below, I want to replace **1234** in  **android:text="1234"** with special characters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1234" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? Show us your code

Comment: what do you mean by 'button name' is it the `android:text` or the `android:id`

Comment: Just paste the text in your code/xml resource file. It should works fine as long as the file is encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Unicode character hexa position](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0370) just prefix it with `\u` inside `String`

`"Ά"` = `(char)0x0386` = `"\u0386"`